# Reply to specific whatsapp message on whatsapp api

Tags: api, twilio, whatsapp, reply

I am tryin to send a reply to a specific whatsapp message, which is done by sliding the message to the right. But on my received POST (send through Twilio), I don't find anything that can denote the referenced message. How can I do this please?

Here is my received POST:

```
From
    whatsapp:+1xxxxxxxxxx
SmsStatus
    received
ApiVersion
    2010-04-01
NumMedia
    0
To
    whatsapp:+1xxxxxxxxxx
SmsSid
    SM5a95d16b24ac16e2ab3b0de6a6304da7
AccountSid
    ACxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
MessageSid
    SM5a95d16b24ac16e2ab3b0de6a6304da7
SmsMessageSid
    SM5a95d16b24ac16e2ab3b0de6a6304da7
NumSegments
    1
Body
    Hi
```

Answer (score 4):

I got the reply from twilio support that you can not track the conversations

> As for "which confirmation is for which message", unfortunately, you
>   won't be able to track the conversation's sequence via our API.